# What does the expression "got smoked" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

> *The WEBP library **got smoked**. The exploit allows for arbitrary code execution. Update your browsers immediately!!* —[Twitter](https://twitter.com/endermanch/status/1707447199917920275?s=20)

Could anybody explain what does mean the expression "got smoked" in the paragraph above?

Would it be "vulnerable"?

Comment: Burned up, burned down, killed, destroyed, overcome, nullified, defeated (etc).

Comment: Apart from the general usages Michael Harvey lists, electrical components especially can get "fried" or "smoked" and by extension that can be said of the entire system that depends on electrical components  or of non-hardware components in such a system (e.g. software) and can be said of the company or organization that relies on such systems.  In this context, when the library gets smoked it means the computer system it relies on got smoked.

Comment: @TimR Whilst, in general, your comment and that of Michael Harvey is correct, it doesn't apply in this case. See SegNerd's answer below for the correct meaning in this context. No computer systems caught fire in this case, it was part of the underlying software security infrastructure that metaphorically "got smoked", that was compromised by a security exploit.

Comment: @PeterJennings  The extended figurative use is not referring to actual fires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means it got severely defeated.

In this case, it is talking about a security exploit that allowed people to circumvent safeguards in the software. But you could use it in other contexts as well, such as “(Product 1) simply smokes (Product 2) in (characteristic).”

Comment: My daughter totally smoked her algebra test this week!